# How do I show the convergence or divergence of the sequence $a_{n}=b^n/2^n$ where $n \in N$ and $b>1$.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show the convergence or divergence of the sequence $a_{n}=b^n/2^n$ where $n \in N$ and  $b>1$.

I tried using the ratio test

$a_{n+1}/a_{n} = [{b^{n+1}/2^{n+1}}]*[{2^n/b^n}] = b/2$

I can't arrive at any conclusion because it is given $b>1$

Comment: Do you know in general about $c^n$ what happens?

Comment: @arberavdullahu that if 0<c<1 then $c^n$ $n\to \infty$ converges?

Comment: Yeah only here you have that $c=\frac{b}{2}$ and that $b>1$. Also look the answer below.

Comment: @arberavdullahu Yes I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a)^n = \infty ~~~\text{(where a > 1)}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a)^n = 1 ~~~\text{(where a = 1)}$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a)^n = 0 ~~~\text{(where 0 < a < 1)}$$

There is no single answer.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n= \begin{cases} \infty~ \text{(diverging)} ~~~~\text{if}~~ b>2 
\\ 1  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if}~~~ b=1
\\ 0 ~\text{(converging)} ~~~\text{if}  ~~ 1<b <2 
\end{cases}  $$